# DynamoDB Scan using AndroidSDK

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am new to working with `DynamoDB` and I need help retrieving data from table using AndroidSDK.

If I have a table called **Location** with the following Attributes:

> { randomID(PrimaryKey)  |  Country  |  States  |  Area  }

How can I scan the table to retrieve all the **States** when a particular country is selected?

In SQL I would say something like:

> SELECT * from States WHERE Country = Germany

Should I use a Query or a Scan?

So far I have seen scan example codes on AWS blogs using `DynamoDBScanExpression` and Condition filters. To be honest I really do not understand.

So I will appreciate if someone can use my above use case to explain how to scan using the AndroidSDK.

Comment: You received a substantial answer the day after asking this - was it any good? It is customary to vote on, accept or reply to helpful people here.

Comment: Downvoted (see above).

Answer (score 1):

I should start by recommending you to avoid **Scan** operations as much as you can. Unless it's necessary of course (*and by necessary, I mean, you really need to fetch **all** the items on a table*).

---

Let's recap how DynamoDB queries work.
In order to make a **Query**, you must know the table's hash key. It's mandatory. You cannot make a query if you don't know it.

Judging by your table's design, I would guess that you probably don't know yours (since it's some random ID), so as a starting point, I'd change your table layout.

Let's say that we chose the `country` name as the hash key.
We have two branches here.

1. We can either make `country` our primary key also, so there will be
   one item per country, and you'll have to store the `states` in a
   list (which is nice, but not optimal).
2. Or we can chose `state` to be a range key, making the primary key a composite key (hash-key and range-key). This would allow us to have an item per state in a country. Which is ideal.

The primary purpose of range keys is to be used in queries. Usually there are a lot of range key values for a particular hash key value. In other words, a lot of states for a particular country.

You would be able to build the following query:

```
#c = :c
```

Where `#c` is an expression attribute name, which holds the value of `country`, and `:c` is an expression attribute value, which holds the value of `Germany`.

This query will return all the items which matches that hash key, which in our case, are all the different states.

If you would like to query for all states starting with the letter `'F'` you may do:

```
#c = :c and begins_with(#s, :s)
```

Where `#c` and `:c` are the same values as before, and `#s = state` and `:s = F`

---

As an extra tip, you **should always** identify what kind of queries you will be making to the table, and then design your table according to these queries. Not the other way around.